# Deleting key/val hash pair leaves behind key. Why?

Tags: perl, hash

Consider the following code:

```
$foo{'bar'}->{'lala'} = "lol";
delete($foo{'bar'}->{'lala'});
```

When I run this code, I expect the "lala" entry to be completely gone (key and value). However, when I use Dumper to dump this hash, it looks like such:

```
$foo => {
    'bar' => {
        'lala' => {}
    }
}
```

Why is the key staying behind? I want to remove both the value AND the key. Following is the actual relevant code and the results.

Code used to delete:

```
delete( $state->{calls}->{$call_id} );
```

Output BEFORE:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
  'packet' => {},
  'calls' => {
    ' 1330718109168
' => {
      'eventcount' => 0,
      'caller_id_name' => ' 
',
  '    channels' => [
        ' 1330718109168
'
      ],
      'entered_time' => 1330718109,
      'caller_id_num' => ' 
'
    },
    ' 1330718097167
' => {
      'eventcount' => 277,
      'caller_id_name' => ' Cell Phone   NY
',
      'channels' => [
        ' 1330718097167
'
      ],
      'queue' => ' TEST_HUD_AMIEV
',
      'entered_time' => 1330718097,
      'caller_id_num' => ' 5555555
'
    }
}, 'main' );
```

Output AFTER:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
  'packet' => {},
  'calls' => {
    ' 1330718097167
' => {},
    ' 1330718109168
' => {}
}, 'main' );
```

Comment: Please post the exact program and output.  The program you have shown will delete the `lala` key.  The output you have shown is not exactly what Data::Dumper would produce.

Comment: enhanced the question to have more real results, and the true delete statement I am using.

Comment: The BEFORE snippet is missing a `}`

Comment: I've updated my answer to match your updated question

Comment: Since I can't answer my own question for another 6 hours... This is solved! Here is whathappened:

Comment: I'll hazard a guess, autovivification?

Answer (score 6):

I cannot reproduce the issue (Perl 5.14.2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %foo;
$foo{bar}->{lala} = 'lol';
delete( $foo{bar}->{lala});
print Dumper \%foo;
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'bar' => {}
        };
```

Comment: Same output in 5.8.9, 5.10.0, 5.10.1 as it should be.

Comment: Ditto.  I cannot reproduce the issue with Perl 5.10.0, either.

Comment: "lala" is gone in ActiveState 5.8.8 on WinXP.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer to updated question:

I cleaned up your sample input to this (with line-end escapes so it can be copy/pasted into the debugger):

```
$VAR1 = bless( \
{ \
  'packet' => {}, \
  'calls' => { \
    '1330718109168' => { \
      'eventcount' => 0, \
      'caller_id_name' => '', \
      'channels' => [' 1330718109168'], \
      'entered_time' => 1330718109, \
      'caller_id_num' => '' \
      }, \
    '1330718097167' => { \
      'eventcount' => 277, \
      'caller_id_name' => 'Cell Phone   NY', \
      'channels' => ['1330718097167'], \
      'queue' => 'TEST_HUD_AMIEV', \
      'entered_time' => 1330718097, \
      'caller_id_num' => '5555555' \
      } \
    } \
}, 'main' )
```

Here's what I get in the debugger:

```
  DB<85> x $VAR1
0  main=HASH(0x108d0a58)
   'calls' => HASH(0x108d09f8)
      1330718097167 => HASH(0x108d0938)
         'caller_id_name' => 'Cell Phone   NY'
         'caller_id_num' => 5555555
         'channels' => ARRAY(0x108d08f0)
            0  1330718097167
         'entered_time' => 1330718097
         'eventcount' => 277
         'queue' => 'TEST_HUD_AMIEV'
      1330718109168 => HASH(0x108d0848)
         'caller_id_name' => ''
         'caller_id_num' => ''
         'channels' => ARRAY(0x108d07b8)
            0  ' 1330718109168'
         'entered_time' => 1330718109
         'eventcount' => 0
   'packet' => HASH(0x108c4408)
        empty hash
  DB<86> delete $VAR1->{calls}->{'1330718097167'}

  DB<87> delete $VAR1->{calls}->{'1330718109168'}

  DB<88> x $VAR1
0  main=HASH(0x108d0a58)
   'calls' => HASH(0x108d09f8)
        empty hash
   'packet' => HASH(0x108c4408)
        empty hash
```

Looks like it's working for me (Perl 5.10.1 on Cygwin)

Comment: This is very informative. Unfortunately, my original question had bad code examples. It turns out I am already using the $foo->{'bar'}->['lala'} convention.